# Decimal Type with Precision Equivalent in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is Spark SQL datatype Equivalent to `DecimalType(2,9)` in SQL?

For example: `print(column.dataType==X)` => should give me True. Where Column's datatype in SQL is DecimalType(2,9)

Tried: `X= DataTypes.createDecimalType(2,9)`, works fine

I am looking for a generalized `DecimalType` Class to filter all `DecimalType` columns from the dataframe irrespective of the precision and scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `DecimalType` type is an instance of `DecimalType` class:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType

df = (spark
  .createDataFrame(["1.32"], "string")
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS value"))

isinstance(df.schema["value"].dataType, DecimalType)
# True
```

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq("1.32").toDF("value")  
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS value")

df.schema("value").dataType match {
  case _: DecimalType => true
  case _ => false
}
// Boolean = true
```

Of course, you'll never encounter `DECIMAL(2,9)`, as it is not possible to have scale greater than precision.